# Django: How to use User ModelForm for log in?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use a modelForm for a login rather than a Form (to avoid repetition):

```py
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            "password": forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = ("email", "password")
```

However, since the email field has a `unique=True`, and since forms can be used to create objects, when running `is_valid()` method on the form, I get an error: `User with this E-mail already exists`.

What is the right way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: please share your view

Comment: Why simply don't remove `uniqe=False`? Share the views and have you used the custom user model or default `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using a generic view and so the view is calling the `save()` method on the LoginForm, and since the LoginForm is a ModelForm it tries to save the user on the database, that's why you have that error.

You could override the `save()` method on your form and just `pass` so nothing get's saved

or (even better) you could just use the [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) from django and set the [USERNAME_FIELD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) on your User model. So you won't need to create your own LoginForm

---

Comment: I'm using a TemplateView and I define the `post` method by myself. I'm pretty sure the `save()` method is never called from this code. It seems there is no need to call `save()` to raise error, but just `is_valid()`.

Comment: BTW, overriding `save()`method with `pass` statement has no effect, confirming my guess.

Comment: Then it's probably the `clean()`, you can check how django creates it's login form https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L174